# Intuitive relation between metrics and measures

Tags: metric, geometry, measure-theory

I understand that a measure is essentially a volume element in a given geometry.

That seems to suggest that a metric is the fundamental object and from it you can derive the measure of a space.

Is this intuition correct? Please elaborate on the relation between the two.

Comment: Beware of assuming that one definition of a word is *the* definition. In particular, "measure" in the fields of probability and statistics has a much broader meaning than you cite and is independent of any geometry. Furthermore, statisticians use "metric" in a less rigorous and far broader sense than in mathematics.  This leaves me wondering what, if anything, your question has to do with statistics and machine learning.

Comment: I work with the compositional data and the Aitchison measure and metric. My definition of metric is based on the mathematical notion of a distance function between elements in a set. I am trying to adapt machine learning algorithms to this setting. If my definition of measure is overly vague or incorrect please elaborate on the portion of a measure that fits with what I have described above and on a more appropriate view of a measure as well.

Comment: I don't know what fits with what you described, because it is so broad and abstract. But frequently "measure" in probability is taken in the sense of certain real-valued functions of sets considered by [measure theory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29)  Moreover, not all metrics produce volume elements: those usually are derived from [Riemannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics) or Minkowskian metrics on manifolds. These considerations suggest your question may be more mathematical or even philosophical in character than statistical.